# Css Float left not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make [this](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=22090721B1B171B7!12786&authkey=!AE8lIzO5HQU2Vho&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cjpg) layout.

So I have tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qy067a07/).

```css
.Projectscontent{
width:1024px;
margin:8% auto;
position:relative;
}

.Desccontent{
  width:200px; 
 

}

.Contentimage{
 background-color:#F00;
 
 width:200px;
 height:40px;
}

.ContentDesc{
 background-color:#F00;
 
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
}

.videoP{
 width:700px;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
  
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="Projectscontent">
    <div class="Desccontent">
      <div class="Contentimage">fdf </div>
      <div class="ContentDesc">dfd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videoP">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/129369632"?autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 width="600" height="575" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But somehow the video is not floating left? Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please upload the image to imgur by clicking on the Image button in the Edit toolbar or by pressing Ctrl+G. This will allow to see it, when it will be deleted from your OneDirve.

Comment: Ok, Ill change it now :)

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, and as always, a simple answer that takes hours to find :P.

For those curious, all I did was add float left to my desccontent. I know. I was adding float to the wrong thing. I hope this helps anyone!

```css
.Projectscontent{
width:1024px;
margin:8% auto;

}

.Desccontent{
  width:200px;
  float:left; 
 

}

.Contentimage{
 background-color:#F00;
 
 width:200px;
 height:40px;
}

.ContentDesc{
 background-color:#F00;
 
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
}

.videoP{
 width:700px;
 
 overflow:hidden;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="Projectscontent">
    <div class="Desccontent">
      <div class="Contentimage">fdf </div>
      <div class="ContentDesc">dfd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videoP">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/129369622"?autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 width="600" height="575" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```